# Iterating through an array list from another class problem

Tags: java, arraylist

This is the class where I store the data:

```
package entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EshopData {
    
    private static ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    
    public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public static void setUsers( ArrayList<User> users) {
        EshopData.users = users;
    }
}
```

This is my main Frame:

```
package ui;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

import entities.User;

public class Frame extends JFrame{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        //FRAME
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My first Eshop");

        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        //frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        

        //LABELS
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Username:");
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Password:");

        l1.setBounds(35, 60, 80, 20);
        l2.setBounds(35, 110, 80, 20);


        //TEXTFIELDS
        JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField tf2 = new JTextField();

        tf1.setBounds(150, 60, 90, 20);
        tf2.setBounds(150, 110, 90, 20);


        //BUTTONS
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Register");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Login");

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                RegisterFrame rframe = new RegisterFrame();
                rframe.setVisible(true);
                rframe.setSize(600, 600);
            }
        });


        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                
            }
        });

        b1.setBounds(35, 150, 100, 20);
        b2.setBounds(160, 150, 80, 20);

        //ADDING TO FRAME
        frame.add(l1);
        frame.add(l2);
        frame.add(tf1);
        frame.add(tf2);
        frame.add(b1);
        frame.add(b2);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
}
```

In my main Frame I have a button "Login" (its the 'b2' button) and I want to create an actionListener that will iterate through the array list from above and search for the User.username, if the username exists it will search for the User.password afterwards.
I am not sure whether I am explaining it correctly or not but any kind of help will be appreciated.

If you need any other part of the code I am here to provide it for you. Thnak's in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom wrapper class for `ActionListener`. This custom class, let's call it `EshopDataBasedActionListener` will contain a field for `EshopData` object. When you create this Listener, you will pass in the actual Object of `EshopData` that has already been created and that contains the user list. Now you are able to access this object inside your listener.

The next part of your problem of binding the Listener to your Login button will now be easier to achieve. You can now provide the implementation of the `actionPerformed` method that will contain your logic. You can pass in the username and password in the same fashion.

Comment: It is not your fault of course but due to the fact that I am new to Java this is giving me a headache. Unfortunately I am not allowed to create another class so is there anything else you can suggest?

Comment: Can there be multiple instances of EshopData in your application? Or only 1?

Comment: I am not sure of what you mean by "Multiple instances" since we are getting teached in Greek and not in English but this is what I thought of doing: 
b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                EshopData obj = new EshopData();
                ArrayList<User> al = obj.getUsers();
                
            }
        });

Comment: What I meant to ask is that in your application do you create the EshopData object only once using new EshopData()? If yes then you can use that reference and do obj.getUsers().